# Chrome extensions and DOM access

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to ask about the principles that developers follow to access DOM elements that don't have a specific class name or have styling classes like (px-2, justify-center, and flex-col) that can be changed by its framework team in the future.

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension to get a LinkedIn profile's primary info like country, username, etc, and find these styling classes in the HTML elements.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You can right click on the element in Devtools and Copy -> Copy selector. No way of doing this independent of framework if there's nothing on the html.

Comment: I tried that but the selector contains an id that is changed every single refresh

Comment: select this `<section id="ember307" data-member-id="999999">` with `[data-member-id]` or `section[data-member-id]`

Comment: It's really a good solution, thanks